# ServiceStack Server Side Events and IIS AppPool Crash

Tags: c#, iis, servicestack, server-sent-events

I am wondering if anyone could help me with some insight / thoughts on an issue we are experiencing with IIS crashes that may be linked with Service Stack Server Side Events?

Our application uses ServiceStack in a Web Application that is hosted in IIS7.  The Web Application utilizes the ServiceStack Server Side Events feature to send some small and time-sensitive data to the clients (Internet Explorer browser application).  For the client-side, we are using a polyfill (Yaffle Event Source) and ss-utils.js to manage the SSE subscribe, unsubscribe, heartbeats, data receiving, etc.

Things function fine, but recently we encountered a complete crash or corruption of the IIS AppPool that is hosting the Web Application with ServiceStack & Server Side Events.  Recently, we turned off IIS AppPool Recycling and we believe this exposed the problem.  However, we don't know what the root cause is.

After the crash/corruption, we saw this in the IIS error log:

```
A worker process '44588' serving application pool '[AppPool]' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.
```

I researched and know that the above error indicates AppPool hit some error state, and a periodic AppPool recycle should keep it functioning properly; however, this isn't ideal and doesn't solve the root problem.

A few minutes before the above IIS error, this ServiceStack related error appeared in the same log:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event ID: fc5b1e959d8343c7acb9b066dff6a927 
Event sequence: 10 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 44588 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ServiceStack.ServerEventsFeature.CanAccessSubscription(IRequest req, String subscriptionId)
   at ServiceStack.ServerEventsHeartbeatHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, String operationName)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://---/---/---/event-heartbeat?id=9GZtp60kxKYpV6n7Mtdq 
   Request path: /---/api/event-heartbeat 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 17 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at ServiceStack.ServerEventsFeature.CanAccessSubscription(IRequest req, String subscriptionId)
   at ServiceStack.ServerEventsHeartbeatHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, String operationName)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContextBase context)
   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.HttpAsyncTaskHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Given the above, I was wondering if the ServiceStack errors are:
  1) the cause of the IIS AppPool crash?
          or
  2) caused by the IIS AppPool crash?

We do experience quite a number of "soft errors" involving clients unsubscribing from the Server Side Events (this is due to the timing of client-server calls and also, some clean-up code that we run to address other issues).  I assume these "soft errors" won't be additive to cause a real/major issue + are really "soft" in terms of they can be ignored safely?

Anyone help on this matter would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of ServiceStack are you using? That StackTrace looks like it may be from a really old version. Can you try upgrading to the latest version to see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Yah, pretty old version (from maybe 1.5-2 years back?): 4.0.41.  I see that the latest is 4.0.56.  It's definitely something we hope/want to try.  I'm unsure whether we'll be able to at this point in the development cycle though given the risk.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution on this?  We are getting similar behavior on 5.2 - IIS hangs and stops accepting requests - even iisreset will hang at that point.  As soon as I remove the ServerEventsFeature, the crashing stops?